# Maximal ideals in a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I am having a lot of trouble figuring out which ideals are maximal in rings that aren't fields.  I read that maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are of the form $(p,f(x))$ where $p$ is a prime number and $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ which is irreducible modulo $p$.
$\\$I am trying to apply this to figuring out if the ideals generated by $x+1$ and $x^2+x+1$ are maximal in $\mathbb{Z}$.  I've been told to consider the ideals $(2,x+1)$ and $(2, x^2+x+1)$ respectively, but I don't get where the two comes from.  Can you pick any prime number to check this condition?  Any explanation of how to proceed would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: $2$ is a prime and $x+1$ and $x^2+x+1$ are both irreducible modulo in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$. So it fits the description.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma so you can use any prime number?

Comment: I think so. But if you use $p$ the polynomial should be irredicible over $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$ instead.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I think then that these would both be maximal, but I've also found this question though which would seem to contradict that: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591558/nonconstant-polynomials-do-not-generate-maximal-ideals-in-mathbb-zx

Comment: These ideals have two generators, not $1$, so what's the contradiction?

Comment: The example uses $2$ as it's the easiest to check irreducibility of $p(x)$ for, I suppose.

Comment: See [here](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/voloch/Homework/zx.pdf) for a proof of your statement.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Ok I see that.  Thank you.  Thats actually where I got the theorem from in the first place.  This may be really dumb since I am teaching myself this course, but I still don't understand why though the ideal (2,x+1) is the same as (x+1)

Comment: $(2,x+1)$ is not the same as $(x+1)$. $x+3$ is in the former but not in the latter.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma So why can we just switch to it to show that (x+1) is maximal in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma why is $M_{1}$ is a proper ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ in the link you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We show that $(x+1)$ is not a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Since $(x+1)\subset (2,x+1)\subset \mathbb{Z}[x]$, we just need to show that $(x+1)\neq (2,x+1)$ and $(2,x+1)\neq \mathbb{Z}[x]$. The first statement holds because $2\notin (x+1)$. The second statement is true by the result you said in the first paragraph.

Comment: Thank you! So similarly for $(x^2+x+1)$, its not maximal because there exists this other ideal $(2,x^2+x+1)$ that contains it but isn't equal to all of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: @VinnyChase Yes. It is similar for the other one, and use the definition of maximal ideal.