# Maximal ideals in polynomial rings over a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I come up with a problem that I cannot figure out. Let $B$ be a UFD and $A=B[y]$ the polynomial ring. Given $f\in A$ containing a term $by^i$ with $i>0$ and $b$ not divisible by some prime element $p\in B$. Prove that $(f)$ is not maximal.

I tried to construct a larger ideal containing $(f)$ by taking $(f,py)$ or $(f,p)$, but I cannot prove that $(f,py)\neq (1)$ or $(f,p)\neq 1$.

Comment: The question is poorly stated and consequently dismissed by a trivial counterexample. The real question is this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591558, and in a comment under my answer I pointed out how to prove it for UFDs having infinitely many non-associated primes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the statement you are trying is not true. Here are my arguments.

Any field has just two ideals, the ones generated by 0 and 1 respectively;  hence it is  PID, and consequently a UFD.

Now take $B$  to be the field of real numbers, a UFD.
Here the polynomial  $f(y) = y^2 +1$ satisfies your hypothesis as it has the term $y^2$, and the coefficient being 1 is not divisible by any prime.

The ideal generated by $f$ is maximal as the quotient by that ideal is the FIELD of complex numbers.

Are we  missing something? Perhaps you have misstated the hypothesis

Comment: I think the assumption is $\exists p\in B$ prime such that $p\nmid b$, which is different from $\forall p\in B$ prime, $p\nmid b$.

Comment: @Acrobatic: yes your point is valid, and I had missed it. But still the "counter-example"  I  have given is valid even when a stronger hypothesis is assumed.

Comment: Thank you. I think all maximal ideals $(x-\alpha)\in\mathbb C[x]$ also serve as counterexamples. The problem is wrong.

Comment: A field does not contain any prime, even though it is a UFD, because prime elements are not $0$ or unit by definition.